# What does git svn clone with no params for layout do?

Tags: git, svn

I have a grouped multi-project repo with the following structure:

http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/PRJGRP/projectN/{trunk,branches,tags}

Let's say I'm cloning project 1; the following commands have the same effect:

- git svn clone -s http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1/project1 project1.git
- git svn clone -T trunk -b brances -t tags http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1/project1 project1.git

My question is, what happens when you clone with none of the parameters?

- git svn clone http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1/project1 project1.git

The first two produce the following config:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1
fetch = project1/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = project1/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = project1/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

The third command produces:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1/project1
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

I wasn't even aware it's possible to not specify a layout; I ran this command by mistake and got this result. The manual page doesn't say anything about cloning an SVN repo without specifying any of these parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll just treat the root of your repository as one big branch, containing your subversion trunk and branches as directories, just as if you did `svn checkout http://my.subversion.host/svn/repos/grp1/project1`.

It *is* possible to pick it apart but that would be a different question and may be more trouble than it's worth if you have time and access to run the clone again.